# dropdown list and distance between element on nav

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I am creating a menu with a picture on the left and some items on the right. An item has a sub-menu (a dropdown menu) and the items in this menu are too far apart between them. How can I fix it? Anyone has any ideas? thank you!

I link the code with css on jsfiddle, thank you!

```
<nav>
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button" >
<ul id="menu">
<li style="float: left; text-align: left;"><img src="/img/logo_desktop.png" alt="logo Scapin Case SRL www.scapincase.com"/>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Proposte Immobiliari</a>
<ul class="hidden">
<li><a href="#">Residence Le Stelle</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Residence Le Vele</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Residence De Nicola</a></li>
</ul>    
</li>
<li> <a href="#">Interni</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Chi Siamo</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tkpuobpw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove

```
margin-top: 60px;
```

from

```
li ul li a {
width: auto;
min-width: 10px;
margin-top: 60px;
padding: 0 20px;
}
```

and add

```
.hidden{
margin-top: 60px;
}
```

to your css file

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the margin-top: 60px from the "li ul li a" selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
li ul li:first-child a {
    margin-top: 60px;
}

li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 10px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

This will eliminate spacing between the items but keep the margin-top on the first element in the dropdown still.

Answer (score 0):

In your css (https://jsfiddle.net/tkpuobpw/) :

The line:

```
padding: 0 20px;
```

makes the gap, so try reducing it.

Hope this will do:

```
padding: 0 4px;
```